# Accessing WCF service sql membership provider from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, membership-provider

I have created a WCF service that is used for authentication. It uses an asp.net SQL membership provider for the accounts.I need a way for the client application to be able to register an account, change password ETC. The way I had originally planned and have started doing was basically interfacing the code within the service by creating matching methods that I could call from the client.

For instance to create the user I would create a method that has all the needed parameters and then within the code body I would access the membership provider so the client could just pass the details into it. So it is all actually done from within the same project/service.

Now that I have started I have began to wonder if I can access the sql membership provider directly from the client so I don't have to waste my time and interface the code.

If so could anyone point me in the right direction on how exactly I create an instance of the sql membership provider in another project so I can access it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a standard framework that is targeted at what you're trying to do, it's called Client Application Services. There's a walkthrough [on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)